# Apache redirect to https without mod_rewrite not preserving URL

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I know there are many similar questions to this, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I recently added SSL to my site with a Let's Encrypt certificate. I am now in the process of forcing all traffic to https, but I have 1 case that I cannot get to work properly.

If the user types in `http://www.example.com/page/`, it gets redirected to `https://www.example.compage`. By dropping the final `/` from the url base, it prevents users from accessing that page directly.

However, `http://www.example.com/page`, `http://example.com/page/`, `http://example.com/page` all work fine. This behavior is the same whether or not the `http://` is included.

I am doing the redirect **without** `mod_rewrite` per the Apache documentation.

Here is my `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://example.com/
  ServerAlias http://www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /path/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The appropriate SSLxx values are set in ssl.conf as well to point to my cert, key, and chain.

Any help is appreciated, as that `/page/` is where users would log into my site, so it is critical and often bookmarked.

Comment: The redirect from `http://www.example.com/page/` to `https://www.example.compage` is not coming from the config shown above, there is either something else in conf files, or there is a `.hataccess` that is causing this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/751562/ssl-redirect-in-virtualhost-causing-url-to-break

Basically, you have to redirect to `https://www.example.com\/`

Apparently Apache tries to strip the final slash if its not escaped for whatever reason.